# CSS Animation Animation Not Fading Out

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm a little stumped trying to sort out a simple animation of a background-image fading in and out on hover. Seemingly the web browser says undefined though my keyframes are defined:

```
  .elementor-section.elementor-element.core-range
     > .elementor-container:hover
     .product-image::before {
     animation: coreRangeBackground 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  @keyframes coreRangeBackground {
     100% { background-image: url("./images/core-range-bg.svg"); }
  }

  .elementor-section.elementor-element.phases-of-the-moon
     > .elementor-container:hover
     .product-image::before {
     animation-name: phasesMoonBackground;
     animation-duration: 0.3s;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
     animation-delay: 0.3s;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  @keyframes phasesMoonBackground {
     100% { background-image: url("./images/phases-of-the-moon-bg.svg"); }
  }
```

**EDIT: Can't animate background images, swapped to opacity**

The image fades in with the ease, but after unhover it just instantly flicks to no image instead of easing out.

```
  .elementor-section.elementor-element.product-card
     > .elementor-container
     .product-image::before {
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     display: block;
     content: "";
  }

  .elementor-section.elementor-element.core-range
     > .elementor-container:hover
     .product-image::before {
     animation: productCardBackgroundHover 0.3s ease-in-out;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     background-image: url("./images/core-range-bg.svg");
  }

  .elementor-section.elementor-element.phases-of-the-moon
     > .elementor-container:hover
     .product-image::before {
     animation: productCardBackgroundHover 0.3s ease-in-out;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     background-image: url("./images/phases-of-the-moon-bg.svg");
  }

  @keyframes productCardBackgroundHover {
     0% { opacity: 0; }
     100% { opacity: 1; }
  }
```

Comment: not sure if this is related but I don't think you can animate `background-image` (although I'm willing to be proven wrong)

Comment: @cornonthecob you may be right, though changed it to a supported css animation of background-color to test and still undefined.

Comment: hmm, that's odd, I'll have another look at your code now and see if I spot any other issues

Comment: @cornonthecob swapped to opacity and its now defined, must just be off for background things for some reason updated question

Comment: ok, for your second issue I would recommend looking at the `transition` property as it will be a lot easier in your case (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Comment: @cornonthecob that was my initial approach but also get the flicker using transition, hence looking for an alternative which stumbled across a strangely working jsfiddle of the animated background image which baffles me how that worked but not supported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254947/discussion-between-corn-on-the-cob-and-daniel-vickers) so we can discuss the best approach to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was the fact the opacity wasn't transitioning, it was because I was setting the background images on hover, so when not hovered it was transitioning out the opacity, however, the image naturally instantly disappeared:

```
  .elementor-section.elementor-element.product-card
     > .elementor-container
     .product-image::before {
     transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     display: block;
     content: "";
     opacity: 0;
  }

  .elementor-section.elementor-element.core-range
     > .elementor-container
     .product-image::before {
     background-image: url("./images/core-range-bg.svg");
  }

  .elementor-section.elementor-element.core-range
     > .elementor-container:hover
     .product-image::before, 
  .elementor-section.elementor-element.phases-of-the-moon
     > .elementor-container:hover
     .product-image::before {
     opacity: 1;
  }

  .elementor-section.elementor-element.phases-of-the-moon
     > .elementor-container
     .product-image::before {
     background-image: url("./images/phases-of-the-moon-bg.svg");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Place the two @keyframes definitions are placed at the beginning.**
I think it will work.